# csshX not working on Mac OS Mojave

Tags: mac, macos-mojave

csshX not working on Mac Mojave.
`csshX root ip1 ip2 ip3`
It doesn't open terminals in different windows, like it is supposed to be.
getting following error:

`**** ERROR **** PerlObjCBridge:: sendObjcMessage: Can't get NSMethodSignature for message "qualifiedSpecifier" 
enter code here
**** ERROR **** PerlObjCBridge: error [1] sending message [NSObject qualifiedSpecifier] at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/PerlObjCBridge.pm line 248.`

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall csshX `(brew uninstall csshX)`
2. Delete related temp files

`rm /Users/userName/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/*
 rm 6078c4a6435b1069dbr5175ee47f855cf4e3f32890fbd143fe36983925d4ce4d--csshx-0.73-2.tar.gz`

3. Install from specific repo of parera10

`brew tap parera10/csshx
 brew install parera10/csshx/csshx`

*(Solution is copied from github, which worked for me)*

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Catalina. Anyone have an alternate fix??

Comment: I have tried this on Catalina only, version 10.15.6.
Please make sure you delete all csshX related temp files & then try